# Как из TimerTask вызвать не статический метод активити?

Tags: android, android-sdk, activity

**Задача такова:** организовать автоматическое обновление контента на активити каждые 5 секунд. 

Проблема в том, что у этого обновления довольно длинный алгоритм, с загрузкой из Интернета, поэтому не статический метод `update()` пришлось делать в класса самого активити.
**Вопрос:**  как его теперь  вызвать из  `TimerTask` ? На другом форуме посоветовали получить указатель на существующий  экземпляр активити. Но как получить этот указатель я тоже не разобрался. В программировании под андроид новичок, заранее спасибо

Comment: Покажите, где вы создаете TimerTask, и как он объявлен у вас. Возможно, достаточно вызвать метод так:    
`<имя класса Activity>.this.<имя метода>`. Например, `MainActivity.this.finish()`

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, следует в активити создать поток, который будет иметь бесконечный цикл с задержкой в 5 секунд и выполнять обновления?

```
Thread thread = new Thread("Update") {
            public void run(){

                try {
                   initUpdate();

                } catch (Exception e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        thread.start();
```

затем

```
 private void initUpdate() {

    while (isWorking){//выключатель нашего обновления

        update(); // сюда вставляем метод, которым обновляем наши данные

        try {
            Thread.sleep(MILLSECUPDATE);//ставим нужное время обновления в миллисекундах
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```